# Como filtrar el nombre del historial de llamadas android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola me gustaría filtrar el historial de llamadas que estoy consiguiendo por android, es decir, mostrar solo las de uno de mis contactos, no tengo muy claro si se puede realizar esto. Acá esta la función que me funciona sin problema:

```
private void getCallDetails() {

    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,  
    null, null, null);

    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int name_count = 
    managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = managedCursor.getString(name_count);
        phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);


            model.add(new Item_llamadas(name, phNumber));



    } //managedCursor.close(); textView.setText(sb); } }
    listapersonalizada.setAdapter(new Adapter_llamadas(this, model));

}
```

Comment: La función te funciona sin problema? cual es el problema si puedes obtener las llamadas, pero no veo que contacto desees obtener, quieres solo un contacto?

Comment: Si, quiero obtener las llamadas de un solo contacto.

Comment: Es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes modificar tu método para definir el nombre del contacto y este realice el guardado únicamente cuando el nombre coincida:

```
   //*Si coincide el nombre del contacto con el registro, guarda el elemento.
            if(nombreContacto.equals(name)){ 

                model.add(new Item_llamadas(name, phNumber));

            }
```

este sería el código completo, como ejemplo `getCallDetails("flo");` para obtener todas las llamadas de "flo":

```
private void getCallDetails(String nombreContacto) {

    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,  
    null, null, null);

    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int name_count = 
    managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        name = managedCursor.getString(name_count);
        phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);

        //*Si coincide el nombre del contacto con el registro, guarda el elemento.
        if(nombreContacto.equals(name)){ 

            model.add(new Item_llamadas(name, phNumber));

        }


    } //managedCursor.close(); textView.setText(sb); } }
    listapersonalizada.setAdapter(new Adapter_llamadas(this, model));

}
```